# Listen for iphone notifications?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

This maybe not possible, but is there a way to "listen" for iphone notifications or check what kind of notifications have come in from within a app? Is there an API for this? Or does Apple not allow it?

Comment: please define what kind of notifications you want to listen for?

Comment: What kind of notifications do you want to listen for ?
If you want to listen for notifications such as phone call, push for others app, sms etc. you can't.

Comment: I think you are asking about [banner notifications](http://www.macworld.com/article/1162978/ios_5_notification_improvements.html). Am I right?

Comment: Yes, banner notifications. For example, if I get a notification from my bank about a transaction, can you listen for this and be able to tell the difference between a bank notification and a text, or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can. Look at [NSNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Here you have [Notification Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html)

Comment: Dont know why anyone would downvote this answer, the question is about notifications without specifying what sort they are looking for. NSNotifications can be altered to suit most situations. Listeners linked to isKindOfClass or custom names would do the job. Upvoting because this is corrent

Comment: The reason why it's not specified is because someone edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

if you're talking about push or local notification, no you can't.

these would be a massive security problem.

unless your talking about your own push notification specifically send to your application, check out [UIApplicationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidReceiveRemoteNotification%3a)